# How to determine right set after set complement operation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say that we have an interval $[-5, 5]$.

How then will look intervals

1. $[-5, 5]\setminus (-1, 1)$
2. $[-5, 5]\setminus [-1, 1]$

My answer is that (1) will be $[-5, -1] \cup [1, 5]$ and (2) $[-5, -1) \cup (1, 5]$, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. (PS: These are not intervals, but union of intervals!)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.
if a

[a,d]-[b,c]=[a,b)\cup(c,d] because "[b" more than b, including it, "c)" means less than c including it.